# Scroll View улетает в бесконечность

Tags: visual-studio, unity3d-editor

Не так давно начал делать проект на Unity.

Потребовалось подгружать информацию из базы. Текст соответственно разного размера. Поэтому я подключил scroll View. Вроде бы всё хорошо. Да только есть проблема, что я могу начать скролить вверх (где текста быть не может) и scroll view улетит в бесконечность. То же самое произойдет, если я начну скролить ниже текста.

Как мне ограничить размер скрол поля? Чтобы оно только по размеру текста.

Структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То, что наложено на Scroll View

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То, что наложено на AdditionalInformace

[image: Наложено на AdditionalInformace]